# Google Login API on Codeigniter is returning empty userinfo. Any ideas?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I have Google Login working on my site, using [codeigniter-oauth2](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2) except that in the last step, all I receive is:

- access_token
- expires

And nothing else!

Here's where I'm requesting the data:

`$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&' .`
`http_build_query(array('access_token' => $token->access_token,));`

It does the full loop, but when I check out:

`file_get_contents($url)` I get nothing!

These are my scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read`

Am I missing a scope? Or am I requesting the information incorrectly?

Also, I'm using `v1`, should I be using `v2` instead?

Comment: you might have better luck with something more recent.  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scopes look incorrect. Try:

- "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"

or

- "profile"

Next, you should make sure your access token is valid. You can use [the tokeninfo endpoint to check your access token](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo), this will tell you things like who the token was issued to and so on.

Finally, as @daimto suggested, you should probably start with [the Google+ PHP example](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php), this will set you up with a client library which makes it much easier to make API calls to Google and work with Google's OAuth 2 implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I swapped in the scope and tried the test, and it seemed to have checked out. I guess the error is happening when I use the access token to get the userinfo by calling `file_get_contents` on: `'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&'.http_build_query(array('access_token' => $token->access_token,)`? Does this look right? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing, since my server doesn't support IPv6, was use Google's Javascript API. I just followed Google's tutorial and it worked fine.